# Is there any way to get a list of connected servers in OS X? (Bash, Obj C, AppleScript...)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, bash, macos, disk

Simply, I'm just looking to get a list of connected remote disks.

I have a script right now that compares /Volumes/ to "diskutil -list" but that only gives me the name of the remote disks, not the actual address.

Anyone have ideas as to how I might go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getfsstat(2)](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getfsstat.2.html)

Comment: interesting. I hadn't come across that function in my searches. I'm also having difficulty finding how to implement it? Any pointers?